# How can I configure launch.json so it could type automatic response?

Tags: python, json, django

'python manage.py collectstatic' almost always requires typing 'yes' or 'no'([preLaunchTask(collecstatic) output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJIZh.png)), before continuing to execute. Can I make it send 'yes' automatically in .json file?
launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "preLaunchTask" : "collectstaticcommand",
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": false
        }, 
    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "collectstaticcommand",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python",
            "args" : [
                "manage.py",
                "collectstatic"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding '--noinput' in the "args":[] in tasks.json